# Charging batteries in series when they are connected in parallel in the circuit

Tags: battery-charging

I'm new to electronics and I'm trying to build a charging circuit for NiMH batteries. There are four batteries in total. Two are in series, and the other two are in series. Then these are connected in parallel. I need to be able to switch them all to series when I plug in the USB for charging. I have an idea and please tell me if it will work. If not could you give me a way, thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBWr89.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

The batteries i'm using are the Eneloop xx which are 1.2v so the USB would work because they add up to 4.8v. I was doing research about charging nimh batteries and found out that it is best to charge them in series and not parallel. So if this wont work than could you help me figure out what will switch it to series?

Comment: Sorry Funkyguy. I'm new to this site I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit doesn't do what you want it to - both batteries are permanently wired in parallel, as is the charger. The diode does nothing.

You probably don't want to charge them in series from USB anyway, because you would need at least 5.6V (1.4V/cell x 4 cells) but you only have 5.0V available. Charging in parallel can be done efficiently with a switch-mode current regulator, or just a resistor to limit current (and perhaps a blocking diode to prevent discharging into the USB port when not powered) if you don't mind a lower charge rate.

Comment: So in series and then parallel like I have, the cells will discharge at the same rate?

Comment: Yes - provided that they have the same internal resistance and state of charge (which is why you should not mix new and old, charged and discharged, or different make/model cells).

Comment: So charging them In parallel would I need a little more than 1.2v or a little more than 4.8v?

Comment: If they are all in parallel then you need a bit more than 1.2V (up to 1.6V if fast charging). If the cells are in individual holders then you should either charge them in series or have a separate charging circuit for each cell, because the battery contacts cannot be guaranteed to have equal resistance. If the battery is to be charged in the device then it may be easier (and more reliable) to have them permanently wired together to form a battery pack (with welded or soldered connections).

Comment: So if I charged them individually I would need 1.6v for each cell or 1.6v for all 4 cells?

Comment: If all the cell negatives (or positives) are connected in parallel then you only need enough voltage to charge one cell, but the current to each cell should be regulated separately. The simplest circuit is simply a resistor form each positive to higher voltage. You add an LED to indicate that the cell is charging,

Comment: [stupid 5 minute edit window!] or use a switching regulator to improve efficiency, or even monitor the cell's voltage and switch the current off when it reaches full charge.

Comment: So how would I cut it off from the rest of the circuit?

Comment: You can use a PNP transistor to regulate current and/or turn the charging current on and off. Here's a circuit which charges 1~4 cells with adjustable current:-  http://powersupply88.com/charger-for-nicd-batteries.html. This is appropriate for charging the cells externally. If you want to charge the battery in circuit then you don't need to isolate each cell but you may need a voltage booster (eg. when charging a 4.8V battery from USB).

Comment: So if I used a dc power source would i still need the rectifier diode bridge? Will it charge nimh batteries. Does it cutoff when charging is complete?

Comment: We are getting sidetracked. Your original circuit shows 4 cells wired in series/parallel, but you can treat them as a single 2 cell pack. Here's a circuit that charges a 2.4V Nimh pack directly from a USB port. It uses a thermistor placed in thermal contact with the battery, which causes it to cut off when the battery heats up at full charge:- http://www.stefanv.com/electronics/usb_charger.html